# flutter doctor 'zsh: command not found'

Tags: flutter, zsh

I have installed flutter and set up the path with the `zsh` file for Catalina version of mac however when I run flutter doctor or flutter precache, I receive `zsh`: command not found: flutter. NOTE: I managed to get through these steps previously and set up android studio however I had issues when I tried to connect the simulator for Xcode and now I have had to start again.

UPDATE: When running 'flutter' or 'flutter doctor', I receive this error: `Error when reading '../../../../documents/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/pub.dart.snapshot': No such file or directory` and it says that `pub upgrade` failed after 10 tries.
How would I solve this?

When I run `ls -a` in the home directory, I see that there's a .bash_profile, a .zshrc file and a .zprofile (which I created previously) in there. Is this related to the problem?

Comment: Open the terminal and check if it says `zsh` on the top or not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes it does. @Rob

Comment: See [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path). You need to update `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: When are you receiving the error that you updated your answer with. Does this mean that you can now run flutter commands and my answer solved your initial issue?

Comment: No, I followed your answer and tried it in different ways too however once that's done and I try to run any flutter commands, I get that error. @JoãoSoares

Comment: If you go the directory where you have your Flutter SDK installed, go into the the bin directory and run `flutter doctor` is it working properly?

Comment: I receive the same error when I do this. @JoãoSoares

Comment: Ok, so your issue is with Flutter SDK, not with with the Flutter command not being available in ZSH. I would advise you to mark the answer that helped you as correct and open a new question specific to the new issue you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like you don't have flutter on your PATH in ZSH.

Open your `.zshrc` file in your terminal with

```
nano .zshrc
```

You should see the following at the top of the file

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Add on the second line the path to the bin directory of your flutter SDK location, like mine:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/Users/joaosoares/Projects/flutter/bin
```

Comment: `echo 'export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.zshrc`

Comment: I prefer to have the user understand the change that he is doing than have him run a one line command. But that is a perfectly valid response.

Comment: I prefer not to have the user use `nano` (what about vim? sublime? vscode?) while an editor is not required. At least you can write "Open ~/.zshrc with your preferred editor"

Comment: nano is the most new user friendly, in my opinion. I wrote the response in the way that I found fit. If you have a different opinion, you are free to write your own response.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am now receiving the same error that I had previously which I'll update the question with. @JoãoSoares